# How to move rows in jfxtableview

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, jfoenix

I am new to JavaFX and JFoenix. I went throw the following link and find out how to make a table using jfxtableview.

https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/demos/components/TreeTableDemo.java

In that example, columns can move by default. But rows can't. I go throw several documents but doesn't find any way to do that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: not supported - you have to implement it yourself

Comment: Please, can you give some clue or example for it?

Comment: implement dnd on the cells and add logic to move the items as well